# ImportError when importing from adjacent directory

Tags: python, python-import

I'm aware this has been asked a lot before, but nothing I tried has worked for me. I have the following directory structure.

```
C:\USERS\PC\DESKTOP\MyProject
│   .gitignore
│   conftest.py
│   README.md
│   __init__.py
│
├───.github
│   └───workflows
│           build.yml
│
├───.vscode
│       launch.json
│       settings.json
│
├───dependencies
│       dev_requirements.txt
│
├───src
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───benchmark
│   │       performance.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   └───sorting
│           bubble_sort.py
│           heap_sort.py
│           __init__.py
│
└───tests
    └───sorting
            test_sorting.py
```

(I'm putting everything I have, but `tests`, `dependencies`, `.github`, etc are irrelevant)

---

What I'm trying to do is to import `bubble_sort` and `heap_sort` in `performance.py` **without** *manually* touching altering sys.path

---

What I've tried:

1. Add the following in `performance.py` (vscode doesn't show any lint errors)

   ```py
   from sorting.bubble_sort import bubble_sort


   bubble_sort(None)
   ```

   Result: `No module named 'sorting'`
2. Using relative imports: `from ..sorting.bubble_sort import bubble_sort`

   Result: `attempted relative import with no known parent package` (What?? No known package with all these `__init.py`s in each directory??

---

In case it's relevant, here is my `.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}
```

Comment: perhaps this shed light: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/. Did you add a file `__init__.py` to the folder where you want to import modules?

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Isn't that clear from the directory structure in the question?

Comment: Yes apologies ...

Comment: There’s no “benchmark.py” in your tree diagram.  Where is it and how are you executing it?

Comment: @DavisHerring Sorry, it's the one called `performance.py`. Will edit the question

Comment: This question is almost nonsensical: you want to import a module, supposedly without any entries on `sys.path` with which to find it.  You can of course introduce a script in a directory that will _automatically_ be added to `sys.path` when it is executed, but isn't that cheating the question's requirements?

Comment: @DavisHerring I edited the question to be a bit more clear. I don't want to ***manually*** alter sys.path. But certainly okay if it catches things automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the functions like this:

```
$ cat test.py
#! /usr/bin/env python
from src.sorting.bubble import thesort
thesort()
$ cat src/sorting/bubble.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
def thesort():
    print('hallo from the bubble')
$ python test.py 
hallo from the bubble
```

To go up a level in the directory, I think you need to make a kickstarter script like so (commands from higher level directory):

```
$ cat start.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
from test.test import runscript
runscript()
$ cat test/test.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
from test.src.sorting.bubble import thesort
from benchmark.performance import evalfunc
def runscript():
    thesort()
    evalfunc()
$ cat test/src/sorting/bubble.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
def thesort():
    print('hallo from the bubble')
$ cat benchmark/performance.py 
#! /usr/bin/env python
def evalfunc():
    print('hallo from performance')
$ python start.py 
hallo from the bubble
hallo from performance
```

Comment: Does this follow the folder structure I'm showing? It looks like you're importing from some directory that's parent to sorting, not adjacent to it.

Comment: I am using relative paths. The file "test.py" is in a directory, there is the sub-path "src/sorting" that has "bubble.py". This is the manner to use to import with relative paths.

Comment: I added a way to do it going up a directory, I think you may need to add a 'starting' script that lives in the top-level directory. This top-level script can then become the base of the package path names.